Conditional insert race conditions drizzle ORM
I'm implementing an event registration portal where each event can have up to x bookings, defined by its capacity. How can I build a query that inserts a booking only when the current number of bookings associated with that event is less than the capacity? I want to avoid race conditions. I am using DrizzleORM with pg.
